# How can I perform a dynamic import inside a packaged library in python?

Tags: python, import, pip, packaging, dynamic-import

I'm writing a library that will be packaged and available to install via pip on Pypi. I have a few script targets in my setup.py

```py
"console_scripts": [
    "mlab=install.make_lab:mlab",
    "rlab=install.run_lab:rlab",
    "clab=install.clear_lab:clab"
]
```

These are primarily intended as programmer tools that supplement the main library.

The `mlab` command creates a directory structure as follows inside the users project:

```
laboratory/
          |- lab.py
          |- labmain.py
```

Inside of labmain.py I have a `main()` function.

```py
import laboratory.lab as lab

def main():
    print("I am the main!")
    print(lab.name)
```

I would like to attach this main method to my shell commands.

I have tried this:

```py
import os

def rlab():
    """
    This shell command is used to run a lab.
    """
    lab_dir_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "laboratory")
    if not os.path.isdir(lab_dir_path):
        print("No lab exists... run the mlab command to make a lab.")
    main = __import__("laboratory.labmain")
    os.chdir("laboratory")
    main.main()
```

As well as a direct import using `from laboratory import labmain`

I continue to get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

It is important to note that the `rlab` function is being packaged and then uploaded via twine to testpypi. I am then installing the package in a separate project, which contains the lab structure after I run the `mlab` shell command. Everything seems to work fine, until it's packaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You have to finish filling out the function arguments. You may need to change the `0` to `1` or `-1`

```py
labmain = __import__("laboratory.labmain", globals(), locals(), ['main'], 0)

labmain.main()
```

Also, make sure that the `laboratory` directory is in `sys.path`

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('z:/path/to/laboratory')
```